# Wordskip in vim [ssh from mac to linux]

Tags: linux, mac, vim, vimrc

Word skip (ctrl key and arrow keys) work fine with vim on my mac in terminal. But, when I ssh from my mac to my linux box, ctrl and arrow key do not work (wordskip) instead delete a bunch of lines ! But, option left arrow works (backward wordskip) but option rightkey does not.

Can someone help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + arrow keys in vim are not assigned: all vim is doing is processing the raw characters. You skip one word to the left/right with the command (**not** in insert mode, of course) b/w.

You can find a cheat sheet for Linux vim/vi editor [here](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif).